# Why is my C# IntPtr variable changing when executing unmanaged code that (supposedly) does not change the pointer's value?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to write a wrapper for libusb in C#/.NET and, at some point, I get an unexpected change in one of my `IntPtr` variables. In particular, I perform the following instructions:

```cs
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDevices; i++)
                {
                    IntPtr device = list + i * 8; // "list" comes from libusb_get_device_list
                    if (LibUSBWrapper.libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, out LibUSBWrapper.libusb_device_descriptor descriptor) == 0) // <-- This somehow changes the value of the "device" variable, which is observed when debugging
                    {
                        PrintDevice(device, descriptor);
                    }
                }
```

Here's the complete code for the main form (do note that it's a Windows Forms application; by "main form", I mean the form that opens when the program is started):

```cs
namespace USBbidirPOC
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        IntPtr context = IntPtr.Zero;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LibUSBWrapper.libusb_init_option[] options = Array.Empty<LibUSBWrapper.libusb_init_option>();
            int result = LibUSBWrapper.libusb_init_context(out context, options, options.Length);
            if (result == 0)
            {
                IntPtr numberOfDevicesPtr = LibUSBWrapper.libusb_get_device_list(context, out IntPtr list);
                int numberOfDevices = numberOfDevicesPtr.ToInt32();
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDevices; i++)
                {
                    IntPtr device = list + i * 8;
                    if (LibUSBWrapper.libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, out LibUSBWrapper.libusb_device_descriptor descriptor) == 0)
                    {
                        PrintDevice(device, descriptor);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to init context!");
            }
        }

        private static void PrintDevice(IntPtr device, LibUSBWrapper.libusb_device_descriptor descriptor)
        {
            if (LibUSBWrapper.libusb_open(device, out IntPtr deviceHandle) == 0)
            {
                int result = LibUSBWrapper.libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(deviceHandle, descriptor.iManufacturer, out string manufacturer);
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(manufacturer);
                }
            }
        }

        private void MainForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

...and here's the code for the wrapper around `libusb-1.0.dll`:

```cpp
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace USBbidirPOC
{
    internal class LibUSBWrapper
    {
        public enum libusb_option
        {
            LIBUSB_OPTION_LOG_LEVEL = 0,
            LIBUSB_OPTION_USE_USBDK = 1,
            LIBUSB_OPTION_NO_DEVICE_DISCOVERY = 2,
            LIBUSB_OPTION_LOG_CB = 3,
            LIBUSB_OPTION_MAX = 4
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct libusb_init_option
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public libusb_option option;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public int iVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public IntPtr log_cbval;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct libusb_device_descriptor
        {
            public byte bLength;
            public byte bDescriptorType;
            public short bcdUSB;
            public byte bDeviceClass;
            public byte bDeviceSubClass;
            public byte bDeviceProtocol;
            public byte bMaxPacketSize0;
            public byte idVendor;
            public byte idProduct;
            public byte bcdDevice;
            public byte iManufacturer;
            public byte iProduct;
            public byte iSerialNumber;
            public byte bNumConfigurations;
        };

        [DllImport("libusb-1.0.dll")]
        public static extern int libusb_init_context(out IntPtr ctx, libusb_init_option[] options, int num_options);

        [DllImport("libusb-1.0.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr libusb_get_device_list(IntPtr ctx, out IntPtr list);

        [DllImport("libusb-1.0.dll")]
        public static extern int libusb_get_device_descriptor(IntPtr dev, out libusb_device_descriptor desc);

        [DllImport("libusb-1.0.dll")]
        public static extern int libusb_open(IntPtr dev, out IntPtr dev_handle);

        [DllImport("libusb-1.0.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(IntPtr deviceHandle, byte iManufacturer, out string manufacturer);
    }
}
```

Let's suppose the `list` variable has a value of `0x00000173f33a11b0` and that `i == 1`. Then, as I debug the program, I observe that `device` has a value of `0x00000173f33a11b8` (which I believe is correct) when executing the `IntPtr device = list + i * 8;` line. However, as soon as the `LibUSBWrapper.libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, out LibUSBWrapper.libusb_device_descriptor descriptor)` instruction is executed, `device` changes to something along the lines of `0x00000173f33a0000`; I expected that `device` would keep its value (`0x00000173f33a11b8`).

Why is this? Do note that this ultimately causes problems down the line (especially if I want to print the USB device's data as per the `PrintDevice` method). Also, I have checked libusb's source code, and didn't find any evidence of `libusb_get_device_descriptor` changing the value for the first argument (see also: https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/master/libusb/descriptor.c#L531).

Comment: This is not possible in the way you describe, because `device` is passed by value not by ref. So it sounds like something is messing up the stack, possibly because it's not reading from the right place. Looks like `list` is actually a pointer to a *list* of pointers, so you can't just add `i * 8` and pass it in directly, you need to deref `list` using `Marshal.ReadIntPtr`. You are also missing a call to `libusb_free_device_list()`

Comment: I agree - sounds like something has clobbered the stack. Calling convention looks correct (stdcall) charlieface is likely correct.

Comment: From your comments, and if I understand correctly, what I would then have to do is something like this (assuming I want the device at index 0 for now)? `IntPtr numberOfDevicesPtr = LibUSBWrapper.libusb_get_device_list(context, out IntPtr listPtr); // listPtr is actually a libusb_device ***` `IntPtr list = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(listPtr); // de-reference listPtr, thus obtaining a libusb_device**` `IntPtr device = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(list); // de-reference list, thus obtaining a device*`

Comment: The libusb_device_descriptor declaration is not correct.  It is too small, causing the native code to copy too many bytes into the space reserved by the C# compiler.  Which overwrites adjacent variables, like that IntPtr.  The idVendor, idProduct and bcdDevice fields are ushort, not byte.  https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/6cf58bac95ff62cd3453cba2c898993b40e1da66/libusb/libusbi.h#L653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by Hans Passant was right on the mark! The stack was being clobbered due to an incorrect declaration of the `libusb_device_descriptor` struct.

Also, thanks to Charlieface, I was able to correctly de-reference the `list` pointer.

Here's the corrected version of the code:

MainForm.cs

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using static USBbidirPOC.LibUSBWrapper;

namespace USBbidirPOC
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        IntPtr context = IntPtr.Zero;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            libusb_init_option[] options = Array.Empty<libusb_init_option>();
            libusb_error result = libusb_init_context(out context, options, options.Length);
            if (result != libusb_error.LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Unable to init context!\r\nError: {result}");
                return;
            }

            IntPtr numberOfDevicesPtr = libusb_get_device_list(context, out IntPtr list);
            if ((int)numberOfDevicesPtr < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Unable to init context!\r\nError: {(libusb_error)(int)numberOfDevicesPtr}");
                return;
            }

            int numberOfDevices = numberOfDevicesPtr.ToInt32();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDevices; i++)
            {
                IntPtr device = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(list + i * 8);
                result = libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, out libusb_device_descriptor descriptor);
                if (result == libusb_error.LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
                {
                    PrintDevice(device, descriptor);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    break;
                }
            }
            libusb_free_device_list(list, 1);
        }

        private static void PrintDevice(IntPtr device, libusb_device_descriptor descriptor)
        {
            libusb_error result = libusb_open(device, out IntPtr deviceHandle);
            if (result == libusb_error.LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
            {
                StringBuilder manufacturer = new(1024);
                result = libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(deviceHandle, descriptor.iManufacturer, manufacturer, manufacturer.Capacity);
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer: " + manufacturer);
                }
                StringBuilder product = new(1024);
                result = libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(deviceHandle, descriptor.iProduct, product, product.Capacity);
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Product: " + product);
                }
                libusb_close(deviceHandle);
                return;
            }
        }

        private void MainForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

LibUSBWrapper.cs

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace USBbidirPOC
{
    internal class LibUSBWrapper
    {
        public enum libusb_error
        {
            LIBUSB_SUCCESS = 0,
            LIBUSB_ERROR_IO = -1,
            LIBUSB_ERROR_INVALID_PARAM = -2,
            LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS = -3,
            LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_DEVICE = -4,
            LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND = -5,
            LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY = -6,
            LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT = -7,
            LIBUSB_ERROR_OVERFLOW = -8,
            LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE = -9,
            LIBUSB_ERROR_INTERRUPTED = -10,
            LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_MEM = -11,
            LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED = -12,
            LIBUSB_ERROR_OTHER = -99
        }

        public enum libusb_option
        {
            LIBUSB_OPTION_LOG_LEVEL = 0,
            LIBUSB_OPTION_USE_USBDK = 1,
            LIBUSB_OPTION_NO_DEVICE_DISCOVERY = 2,
            LIBUSB_OPTION_LOG_CB = 3,
            LIBUSB_OPTION_MAX = 4
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct libusb_init_option
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public libusb_option option;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public int iVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public IntPtr log_cbval;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct libusb_device_descriptor
        {
            public byte bLength;
            public byte bDescriptorType;
            public ushort bcdUSB;
            public byte bDeviceClass;
            public byte bDeviceSubClass;
            public byte bDeviceProtocol;
            public byte bMaxPacketSize0;
            public ushort idVendor;
            public ushort idProduct;
            public ushort bcdDevice;
            public byte iManufacturer;
            public byte iProduct;
            public byte iSerialNumber;
            public byte bNumConfigurations;
        };

        [DllImport("libusb-1.0.dll")]
        public static extern libusb_error libusb_init_context(out IntPtr ctx, libusb_init_option[] options, int num_options);

        [DllImport("libusb-1.0.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr libusb_get_device_list(IntPtr ctx, out IntPtr list);

        [DllImport("libusb-1.0.dll")]
        public static extern libusb_error libusb_get_device_descriptor(IntPtr dev, out libusb_device_descriptor desc);

        [DllImport("libusb-1.0.dll")]
        public static extern libusb_error libusb_open(IntPtr dev, out IntPtr dev_handle);

        [DllImport("libusb-1.0.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern libusb_error libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(IntPtr dev_handle, byte desc_index, StringBuilder data, int length);

        [DllImport("libusb-1.0.dll")]
        public static extern void libusb_free_device_list(IntPtr list, int unref_devices);

        [DllImport("libusb-1.0.dll")]
        public static extern void libusb_close(IntPtr dev_handle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure why you are seeing that, but I'd guess the stack is getting messed up somewhere.

It looks like `list` is actually a pointer to a *list* of pointers, so you can't just add `i * 8` and pass it in directly, you need to deref it using `Marshal.ReadIntPtr`.

- `libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii` should have been declare with `CharSet.Ansi`=, it should have passed in a `StringBuilder` buffer, and it's also missing a parameter.
- You are also missing calls to `libusb_close` and `libusb_free_device_list`.
- You should declare the return type as `libusb_error` and check it for errors.

```cs
enum libusb_error
{
  LIBUSB_SUCCESS = 0,
  LIBUSB_ERROR_IO = -1,
  LIBUSB_ERROR_INVALID_PARAM = -2,
  LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS = -3 ,
  LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_DEVICE = -4 ,
  LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND = -5 ,
  LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY = -6 ,
  LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT = -7 ,
  LIBUSB_ERROR_OVERFLOW = -8 ,
  LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE = -9 ,
  LIBUSB_ERROR_INTERRUPTED = -10 ,
  LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_MEM = -11 ,
  LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED = -12 ,
  LIBUSB_ERROR_OTHER = -99
}

[DllImport("libusb-1.0.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern libusb_error libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(
  IntPtr dev_handle, byte desc_index,
  StringBuilder data, int length);
```

Then you need to deref the pointer

```cs
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LibUSBWrapper.libusb_init_option[] options = Array.Empty<LibUSBWrapper.libusb_init_option>();
    int result = LibUSBWrapper.libusb_init_context(out context, options, options.Length);
    if (result != libusb_error.LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Unable to init context!\r\nError: {result}");
        return;
    }

    IntPtr numberOfDevicesPtr = LibUSBWrapper.libusb_get_device_list(context, out IntPtr list);
    if ((int)numberOfDevicesPtr < 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Unable to init context!\r\nError: {(libusb_error)(int)numberOfDevicesPtr}");
        return;
    }

    int numberOfDevices = numberOfDevicesPtr.ToInt32();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDevices; i++)
    {
        IntPtr device = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(list + i * 8);
        result = LibUSBWrapper.libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, out LibUSBWrapper.libusb_device_descriptor descriptor);
        if (result == libusb_error.LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
        {
            PrintDevice(device, descriptor);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            break;
        }
    }
    libusb_free_device_list(list, 1);
}
```

```cs
private static void PrintDevice(IntPtr device, LibUSBWrapper.libusb_device_descriptor descriptor)
{
    int result = LibUSBWrapper.libusb_open(device, out IntPtr deviceHandle);
    if (result == libusb_error.LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
    {
        var manufacturer = new StringBuilder(1000);
        result = LibUSBWrapper.libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(deviceHandle, descriptor.iManufacturer, manufacturer, manufacturer.Capacity);
        if (result == libusb_error.LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(manufacturer);
        }
        libusb_close(deviceHandle);
        return;
    }
}
```